# Sealing Carpet and Baseboards

Tags: pest-control, baseboard, carpet, insect, tape

Would it be okay to use duct tape (or any kind of tape) to seal the space between carpet and baseboards? I've had various run-ins with pests and have always seen bugs come from baseboards and windows.

This would be a precaution and since I'm renting a room, I don't want to have to peel back the carpet. I also use caulking for outlets/windows, and use Cimexa Dust.

Comment: What sort of pests are you thinking about?

Comment: I didn't have a specific pest in mind. Just general ones I've seen over the years (carpet beetles, spiders, silverfish, booklice, ants). In addition to the cimexa dust and caulking, I also use a dehumidifier to keep humidity in the 40's. Just wondering if there are any downsides to using the tape?

Comment: Since you're renting, talk to the landlord. Either he may be willing to caulk for a permanent solution, or let you do the caulking and turn in your receipt for materials as a partial rent payment. It would be a better long-term solution. Also, are bugs _currently_ present? If so, you've got a bit bigger stick to get the landlord moving, if not, it's just a "future concern" and he may not be quite as motivated as you are.

Comment: Bugs are not currently present. I just do this as a precaution. I'm not sure how she could caulk since its carpet and baseboards.

Comment: Remove baseboard, peel back the carpet from the tack strips (if necessary), caulk whatever gap may be there, tighten carpet & reattach to tack strips, reinstall baseboard.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will see if she can have someone do that before I move in next week.